# Find C1 so that f is a Join Density Function

Tags: calculus, functions, density-function

How exactly can I find the value of $C_{1}$ so that f is a joint density function?

$$f(r,\theta)=
\begin{cases}
C_{1}(1-r^{2}), & \text{if} (r,\theta)∈ R\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Where R is the region inside of r = 2+4cosθ (which includes the inner loop)

Comment: The integral of the density function, over the entire region, must be 1.

Comment: Why will it be 1? If you are confident thats the answer post an answer with your work.

Comment: That follows from basic definitions.  The probability of an event is always from 0 to 1.  The probability of something that CANNOT happen is 0, the the probability of some that is SURE to happen is 1.  And the probability density is defined as the derivative or the probability function so the probability function is the integral of the probability density function.  The integral of the probability density over the entire region covers all possible outcomes so is necessarily 1.

Comment: I know I will get a value between 1 and 0 for C1  but I dont know how to get that answer that is what I am asking.